# Unable to load image in img control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have image control.I want to load image from my specific path.
i have a code in page behind

```
string imagePath ="E:/DotNetProjects/Templates/Default/icons/Computer.png";
imgEditor.ImageUrl = imagePath;
imgEditor.AlternateText = "Unable To Find Image";
```

path is exist and image is also available but always load alternate text.
`imgEditor` is my image control ID.
 Plz help to catch my mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your image in solution(any folder or even in root) and path image uri from that (with src in asp page) like :

```
src="Templates/Default/icons/Computer.png"
```

Comment: i got a solution .` Request.ApplicationPath + "/Templates/" + filename`

Answer (score 0):

The `imagePath` is a filesystem path... you need a URL... (something like `http://...`). The URL must be accessible from the browser i.e. you need to setup your webserver (IIS) to serve the respective path... I would recommend putting the image into the solution/project so that the URL is relative...

Comment: in this case he can use ~/Image file Path

Comment: then you need to set the URL relative (i.e. starting with `~/`) and let it point to the right location!